# Restricting the call on a method

Tags: c#, .net

I need to restrict the calling of a method from a particular method.

For example:

I've a function like `GetData()` and I need its calling method's signature to be 
void `SomeFUnction(string a, String b)`
otherwise the calling of `GetData` should not be allowed at compile time itself.

Comment: Maybe you can write an FxCop rule for something like this.

Comment: I don't think you really *do* need this functionality. Is there a particular use case for requiring this? It sounds like a terrible idea without having an explicit use.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it at compile time.

Comment: In fact, he *can* do it at runtime. He can't do it (without an external tool) at compile-time.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just mistyped. I meant **compile** time, of course.

Comment: So can I restrict like the calling class should implement a particular interface. I need this too at compile time. can I get this happen by using any constraints for the method which is supposed to be called?

Comment: @Eldhose: To do this at compile time, you need to change the design of this code. If you have the freedom of changing the design, then you can implement a "visitor" pattern and force a particular interface on the "caller".

Comment: Yes I can change the design. I'm doing this for self study perpose. Please guide me on visitor pattern.Thanks...

Comment: @Eldhose, functions aren't supposed to know anything about what is calling them. The whole point is that they have a job, and they do it. The class containing the function has the role of determining what can or can not access their functions. Do you want to try and explain why you're attempting to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to restrict that "GetData" could be called from "SomeFuncion(...)", then you can easily do that by encapsulating your method in a class (instance/static) and making the "GetData" method private, and only call it from your "SomeFunction(...)". How else could you restrict this at compile time!!.

Though, I believe you are not sharing the exact problem statement here.
Instead, you are sharing a thought that you percieve as a possible solution to your problem!!.

Sharing the exact problem statement will fetch you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This does not create a compile time break.  However, if test coverage is hitting all calls of GetData(), this'll do what you are looking for by breaking tests.

```
public void GetData()
{
   // last method up the stack trace
   var callingMethod = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

   var returnType = callingMethod.ReturnType;
   // throw exception if not okay

   var callingMethodParameters = callingMethod.GetParameters();
   // throw exception if not okay

   // GetData implementation
}
```