# In C#, how to restrict who can call a method at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compile-time

In C#, is it possible to restrict who can call a method at compile time?

I've looked into directives, but that didn't work since I can't assign values to symbols.

```
#define WHO VisualStudioUser.Current // does not work
```

I also looked into Code Access Security (CAS) but that's runtime enforcement, not compile time.

The requirement is to restrict access to a method at compile time for specific developers given the method exists in a pre-compiled assembly.

here's more details...
I'm building a framework or a series or assemblies for a team of developers. Because of our software license restrictions, I can only allow a few developers to write code to make a call to some restricted methods. The developers will not have access to the source code of the framework but they'll have access to the compiled framework assemblies.

Comment: That's what `private` was invented for.

Comment: What does "specific developers" mean? What kind of restrictions?

Comment: Probably you have to be more specific.
Is it connected to the security restrictions?
Or is this something related to application design?
Or do you want just to add something which will behave differently depends on user?

All this thing are reasonable but your question is not (in its current form).

Comment: How do you use "private" to restrict specific developers from calling it? The restriction can be in the form of compiling error if a unauthorized developer made the method call.

Comment: Your question is down voted. I disagree with this but I think you should give us details

Comment: But developers don't make a method call, the code does. Or at the most a user does.

Comment: @Ray Ok. We have all this fancy thing connected with digital signature of code (update: assembly %) ). This is in fact something similar to the subject of this question

Comment: I think this is a pretty good question, checking security at compile time might come as a feature in future .Net Framework versions..!!

Comment: @RayCheng there is a similar discussion at these links: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/37958/restrict-who-can-call-a-function.aspx  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209204/restricting-the-call-on-a-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The requirement is to restrict access to a method at compile time for specific developers given the method exists in a pre-compiled assembly.

One way is to mark the method `private` or `internal`, it won't be callable by *anyone* outside the assembly. **UPDATE**: Also take a look at the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute, which is used to define which assemblies can "see" internals of your assembly.

Another way is to divide the code you want to distribute from the code you don't want people to call into *separate* assemblies. Maybe you just share an assembly mostly of interfaces with your users, that they them compile against; and you have a separate assembly with implementations that they shouldn't reference directly. Your internal team would have access to the implementation assembly. This is just a common form of dependency management, the [dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: Expanding on your answer, he could use InternalsVisibleTo and restrict it to certain assemblies, and then use source control to only give access those assemblies' source to the developers he wants.

Answer (score 7):

The quick answer will be: No this isn't possible, and if you need to do it, you're Doing It Wrong.

How would this even work? Does it depend who who's running the code or who wrote it?

**Edit** There's kind of a way using InternalsVisibleTo and restricting accessing in source control to the assemblies that InternalsVisibleTo is specified for. See [Jordão's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125175/in-c-how-to-restrict-who-can-call-a-method-at-compile-time/8125370#8125370)

Comment: good idea. I used InternalsVisible before and I think it's a good option if I can have better restriction to the namespace created by the team of developers.

Answer (score 1):

Draft:

1. Compile the restricted code into (obfuscated) DLLs: TypeA.dll, TypeB.dll etc.
2. Define an interface for each type, and compile them into separate DLLs: ITypeA.dll, ITypeB.dll etc.
3. Create a "guard assembly", and [embed](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch16.aspx) all restricted assemblies into it: Guard.dll. This has a ResolveEventHandler, and methods to instantiate different types defined in the embedded restricted DLLs. Instances are returned through their interface.
4. Developers get the interface DLLs and the Guard.dll. Each developer can get a Guard.dll with special authentication tokens in it. For example, a Guard.dll can be bound to PC, an IP address, a GUID issued to the developer, anything.
5. The developer can instantiate those types for which she has the proper authentication code, and uses the object instance through an interface.

Sorry this is a bit fuzzy, because it was more than a year ago when I used these techniques. I hope the main idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using Extensible C# developed by **ResolveCorp**, some of the links for study and implementation are:

http://zef.me/782/extensible-c

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DbCwithXCSharp.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2003/02/14/2412.aspx

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/11579/0/page/5